# What do I need to get Kinect up and running on older 360?

Tags: kinect

I have an older model 360 (not slim). I have heard that they require an additional power supply to work with the older models. Is this true? if so is it included or sold separately. I would hate to not be able to get it up and running xmas morning.

I did find this related [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/778/kinect-compatibility) but it did not answer my specific question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you do need a power supply to run a Kinect on an Xbox Classic (on the newer ones there is an orange port which acts at the power supply).

Currently, all Kinect are sold with such a power supply.

While there is no guarantee this will be true going forward (or true if you buy on ebay); as part of their launch, Microsoft has been including the power supply with all Kinect products sold independently of an Xbox (if you buy one as part of a bundle all bets are off).

[Example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002BSA298).  Notice how, under product description, power supply is included.